# How to enable a new driver in android linux kernel?

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel

To enable a function in Nexus 9, I wrote a driver in the linux kernel, as shown in the following. This driver basically can write values to a specified register. The driver is loaded using `module_param_cb()`.

However, the kernel log shows that this driver is not actually loaded when the kernel starts. Does anyone know the reason, please? I am a totally freshman to linux kernel. Hope someone could provide any suggestions or solutions.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_PASR
static bool tegra132_is_lpddr3(void)
{
    return (tegra_emc_get_dram_type() == DRAM_TYPE_LPDDR2);
}

static void tegra132_pasr_apply_mask(u16 *mem_reg, void *cookie)
{
    u32 val = 0;
    int device = (int)cookie;

    val = TEGRA_EMC_MODE_REG_16 | *mem_reg;
    val |= device << TEGRA_EMC_MRW_DEV_SHIFT;

    emc_writel(val, EMC_MRW);

    pr_debug("%s: cookie = %d mem_reg = 0x%04x val = 0x%08x\n", __func__,
            (int)cookie, *mem_reg, val);
}

static void tegra132_pasr_remove_mask(phys_addr_t base, void *cookie)
{
    u16 mem_reg = 0;

    if (!pasr_register_mask_function(base, NULL, cookie))
            tegra132_pasr_apply_mask(&mem_reg, cookie);

}

static int tegra132_pasr_set_mask(phys_addr_t base, void *cookie)
{
    return pasr_register_mask_function(base, &tegra132_pasr_apply_mask,
                    cookie);
}

static int tegra132_pasr_enable(const char *arg, const struct kernel_param *kp)
{
    unsigned int old_pasr_enable;
    void *cookie;
    int num_devices;
    u64 device_size;
    u64 size_mul;
    int ret = 0;

    if (!tegra132_is_lpddr3())
        return -ENOSYS;

    old_pasr_enable = pasr_enable;
    param_set_int(arg, kp);

    if (old_pasr_enable == pasr_enable)
        return ret;

    num_devices = 1 << (mc_readl(MC_EMEM_ADR_CFG) & BIT(0));
    size_mul = 1 << ((emc_readl(EMC_FBIO_CFG5) >> 4) & BIT(0));

    /* Cookie represents the device number to write to MRW register.
     * 0x2 to for only dev0, 0x1 for dev1.
     */
    if (pasr_enable == 0) {
        cookie = (void *)(int)TEGRA_EMC_MRW_DEV1;

        tegra132_pasr_remove_mask(TEGRA_DRAM_BASE, cookie);

        if (num_devices == 1)
            goto exit;

        cookie = (void *)(int)TEGRA_EMC_MRW_DEV2;
        /* Next device is located after first device, so read DEV0 size
         * to decide base address for DEV1 */
        device_size = 1 << ((mc_readl(MC_EMEM_ADR_CFG_DEV0) >>
                    MC_EMEM_DEV_SIZE_SHIFT) &
                    MC_EMEM_DEV_SIZE_MASK);
        device_size = device_size * size_mul * SZ_4M;

        tegra132_pasr_remove_mask(TEGRA_DRAM_BASE + device_size, cookie);
    } else {
        cookie = (void *)(int)TEGRA_EMC_MRW_DEV1;

        ret = tegra132_pasr_set_mask(TEGRA_DRAM_BASE, cookie);

        if (num_devices == 1 || ret)
            goto exit;

        cookie = (void *)(int)TEGRA_EMC_MRW_DEV2;

        /* Next device is located after first device, so read DEV0 size
         * to decide base address for DEV1 */
        device_size = 1 << ((mc_readl(MC_EMEM_ADR_CFG_DEV0) >>
                    MC_EMEM_DEV_SIZE_SHIFT) &
                    MC_EMEM_DEV_SIZE_MASK);
        device_size = device_size * size_mul * SZ_4M;

        ret = tegra132_pasr_set_mask(TEGRA_DRAM_BASE + device_size, cookie);
    }

exit:
    return ret;
}

static struct kernel_param_ops tegra132_pasr_enable_ops = {
    .set = tegra132_pasr_enable,
    .get = param_get_int,
};
module_param_cb(pasr_enable, &tegra132_pasr_enable_ops, &pasr_enable, 0644);
#endif
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you're not rebuilding and reflashing the kernel? So you're building the driver as a module and then loading it with insmod?

Comment: Thanks, David. Actually I do rebuild and reflash the kernel to nexus 9. But I am not sure if I revised the makefile correctly. I am trying to build the driver as a module, but don't know how. Do I need to generate a .ko file?

Comment: Depends whether you want the driver linked in to the kernel or if you're listing it dynamically. Unfortunately my knowledge of this area is very stale. I'd check to see if a .ko was created, though - if so, it's not part of the kernel (which would explain why it's not started when the kernel loads!).

Comment: Oh, I see. But I think I need the driver linked into the kernel. Then should I use the module_param_cb(), or maybe something like module_init() instead?